# What does a class name in another class parameter list means in Python?

Tags: class, python-3.x

I'm trying to read and understand a program source code written in Python and I got confuse with one thing that appeared in some places in the source code:

```
class Class1(ClassA):
```

This code snippet is repeated in the source code of a .py file, in a way that only "Class1" vary ("`class Class1(ClassA):`", "`class Class2(ClassA):`", "`class Class3(ClassA):`", etc.).

Sorry, but I can't share the source code with you guys, it's part of my friends term paper.

I appreciate any explanation, thanks!

Comment: If you want to know how a given statement or expression works, [the docs have a full explanation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions). It's not a parameter list, it's the base classes for the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax means that `Class1` inherits from `ClassA`.

For further information, see [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).